# Does the Zwicky Transient Facility only run when triggered by a cell phone?

Tags: observational-astronomy, observatory

A *really enjoyable interview* with Mansi Kasliwal & Samaya Nissanke ("From discovery to making precision measurements") is available as a short audio podcast in the BBC News article [Gravitational waves hunt now in overdrive](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-48137011) describes the very recent gravitational wave events and the way optical searches for the source were initiated by pressing a "go button" on a cell phone!

It's a excerpt from the BBC's Science in Action episode [What is behind the Indian Ocean Cyclones?](https://www.bbc.co.uk/programmes/w3csym1m)

The [article](https://www.bbc.com/news/science-environment-48137011) is quite a good read as well, and talks about the [Zwicky Transient Facility (ZTF)](https://www.ztf.caltech.edu/), based on the 48-inch Samuel Oschin Schmidt telescope with several upgrades including a state of the art silicon CCD array replacing the 14 inch square photographic plates it originally used, faster slewing and AI-based recognition of candidate objects.

The huge aperture allows for almost 50 square degree field to be checked down to +20 magnitude every five minutes. That's about one steradian in 5 hours. According to the podcast, it can run as fast as 4000 square degrees per hour, about 1.2 sr/h presumably with a brighter limiting magnitude.

**Question:** Does the ZTF only start surveying when triggered by a cellphone or other alert, or does it continue to search for new objects and events on some nominal routine whenever there is good visibility?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ZTF is operating on most clear nights on an automated queue of pointings. When they discover transients, they inform [TNS](https://wis-tns.weizmann.ac.il/search?&name=&name_like=0&isTNS_AT=all&public=all&unclassified_at=0&classified_sne=0&ra=&decl=&radius=&coords_unit=arcsec&groupid%5B%5D=48&classifier_groupid%5B%5D=null) which may trigger other observatories to point at the same object, just as ZTF may respond to transient events from other observatories.

Comment: Cool, thank you!