# Tracking variable stars?

Tags: star, amateur-observing, variable-star, nova

Is there a website or application I can use do track the brightness of variable stars and notify of any unusual or particularly spectacular changes.
I am particularly interested in tracking the blaze star as it is predicted to outburst soon and it outbursts only rarely

Comment: This is basically the same question, unless you are interested in historical data. https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/57236/automated-and-hopefully-free-systems-i-can-subscribe-to-sending-email-or-sms-t

Comment: @james I am interested in other variable stars as well

Answer (score 2):

The [AAVSO](https://www.aavso.org/)  (American Association of Variable Star Observers) organises and tracks many variable stars.  For example you can see the [latest observations of T CrB](https://app.aavso.org/webobs/results/?star=000-BBW-825&num_results=200) (is this your "blaze star"?). At the time of posting, the most recent observation is within the past few hours and shows it at a nominal 10.3 in the visual "V" band.

They don't do "alerts", but it is simple enough to check their website, type in a star's name (eg "T CrB", or "Algol") and generate a [light curve](https://www.aavso.org/LCGv2/).

You can also subscribe to the [Time sensitive alert](https://www.aavso.org/forum/5012) forum, and get emails about stars that are rapidly changing brightness (as observed by AAVSO members)